# Softkeyboard overlaps multilineEditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have multiline `EditText` in `ScrollView`. I need to make the whole `EditText` visible when keyboard is shown. Now it overlaps the bottom part of `EditText` showing only first line.
I have already read a lot of questions here, tried `adjustPan`/`adjustResize` combinations etc but nothing really helps.

Comment: Add your layout in question.

Answer (score 4):

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_feedback"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:lines="8"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:minLines="6"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    ...
```

`windowSoftInputMode` is the key but personally I found the `configChanges` help too.

And some more info on [Handling Input Method Visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)

Answer (score 0):

use the following xml code for your edittext:

```
 <EditText
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place all your views in a top level ScrollView so that the content can be scrolled when the screen is not as tall as you exepct. It's not a good idea to assume the height of the screen for general layout purposes. Always use a ScrollView if you want your content to be scrollable on all screen sizes and orientations and keyboard states.